# Is there a way to measure server resource (CPU) usage by WP plugins?

Tags: optimization, server, server-load

I have a website who is having a high CPU usage.  The only way I know of it, is the information I get from the support people of the hosting company.

Is there any other way for me to become informed of the resource usage done by my website? (specifically the plugins, but not only them)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a so called profiler to measure which part of your application does make use of CPU and Memory Resources. [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) is such a profiler for example. Using it will show you exactly which part of your application uses how much of CPU and memory.

Comment: Thank you Hakre, I will use this as a basis for a following question.

Comment: Here it is:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/828/profiling-a-wp-website-for-deployment-on-shared-hosting

Answer (score 1):

I have this answer for you. you need to configure an apache module called : apache-status.
there is also a project called pimped apache status wich is build on this apache feature: here is the info : https://github.com/axelhahn/pimped-apache-status

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely difficult / impossible to get the data on CPU usage on different plugins. They are after all just php functions. But because functions get called all over the place when a page is generated it's hard to see what's using how much.

What you could do is to measure all of php. You could try to disable/ enable plugins. This will give you an indication. But CPU usage can very much depending on content, users etc.

Comment: Thanks GT.  Do you know of a plugin that might do this automatically ?

Comment: Not a plugin, but a PHP extension, see my answer. So to say, yeah, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this automatically but if you use SSH you can run the top command and watch it while you were on the website using whatever the plugin does to see if it spikes.

You can also do this in Cpanel but you would have to continually refresh the page.